# Run Lengths (python )

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm supposed to create a list where it takes account if heads or tails is consecutive... ie. [H,H,H,T,T,H,H,T,T,H,T] = [ 3,2,2,2,1,1] 
why isn't this working?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def run_lengths(n,p):
    tosses= np.random.choice(([True, False ]),p=[p,1-p], size=n)
    heads= True
    tails= False
    heads_counter = 0
    tails_counter=0
    runlist=[]
    rl=runlist
    for i in tosses:
        if True:
            heads_counter+=1
            if tosses[i+1]== False:
                rl.append(heads_counter)
                heads_counter=0
        elif False:
            tails_counter +=1
            if tosses[i+1]== True:
                rl.append(tails_counter)
                tails_counter=0
    print(runlist)
    print(tosses)
##print(run_lengths(10,.5))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `[len(list(g)) for _, g in itertools.groupby(tosses)]`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you're referring to

Comment: Try `import itertools`; and then running that code and seeing if it gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, why do you even need separate counters, if you're just counting consecutive values of <whatever>?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate heads and tail counters. Just use a variable to hold the previous element of the list, and compare the current element to it. If it's the same, increment the counter. If it's different, append the counter to the result list and reset the counter. After the loop, append the final counter.

Also, `if True: ... elif False:` is nonsense. The `True` branch will always be taken. I guess you meant `if i == True:`. Or maybe `if i == heads:` (you never actually use the `heads` and `tails` variables).

```
import numpy as np
def run_lengths(n,p):
    tosses= np.random.choice(([True, False ]),p=[p,1-p], size=n)
    last_toss = tosses[0]
    counter = 1
    runlist = []
    for toss in tosses[1:]:
        if toss == last_toss:
           counter += 1
        else:
           runlist.append(counter)
           counter = 1
           last_toss = toss
    runlist.append(counter)     
    print(runlist)
    print(tosses)

run_lengths(15, .5)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/thpB64)